# Double if else without brackets

Tags: c#, if-statement

I recently discovered that you can use the following syntax for if/else statements:

```
if (a)
    b = true;
else
    b = false;
```

when you nest another if clause inside this, it gets confusing

```
if (a)
    if (b)
         c = 3;
else
    c = 1;
```

but since the compiler ignores line indents, the compiler always parses this as (from what I understand)

```
if (a)
    if (b)
         c = 3;
    else
         c = 1;
```

Is it possible to achieve the second clause without using brackets? (I am aware that this makes no difference, but it is cleaner in my opinion)

---

**EDIT: For all the comments suggesting something along the lines of the following:**

```
if (a && b)
    c = 3;
else
    c = 1;
```

**This is not the same. if a = true and b = false, c will be set to 1, but the expected value is that it wouldn't be set at all.**

Comment: completely useless: if (a)
    if (b)
         c = 3; else ;
    else
         c = 1;

Comment: if (a && b) c = 3; else c =1;

Comment: If you're more comfortable with the brace-less, white-space-determined blocks, you might want to give F# a try. Doing this in C# is going to make a lot of people rather angry - it makes the code incredibly hard to read and reason about. Don't bring your style over to a new language *unless it actually helps* - in this case, it decidedly does not, and it's going to make the life of anyone maintaining your code a huge pain.

Comment: No, it is not possible to achieve this without the brackets.

Comment: @Kris this is not the same, if you would do it like that, if a = true and b = false, it will set c to 1 which is not the expected behaviour.

Comment: `if(a && b)  b = true; else  b = false;`

Comment: Why would you want to *intentionally* introduce ambiguity to your code? Use the damn brackets :)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I don't write my code like this, I found it interesting and I was just wondering if it was possible at all.

Comment: @L0laapk3 oh, good then. You already got the short answer. The slightly longer one is: you can't change a language's precedence rules just like that. They're built in the compiler and are applied right from the CST construction pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **mutli-lines** condition you must put braces. C# don't care about indentation like Python..

```
if(condition)
//enter if statement
//leave if statement
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to bring over your own language into C#, why not in style? Define an `If` method!

```
public static void If(Func<bool> condition, Action ifTrue, Action ifFalse = null)
{
  if (condition()) ifTrue(); else if (ifFalse != null) ifFalse();
}
```

Then you can represent your code with

```
var a = false;
var b = true;
var c = 0;

If(() => a, () => If(() => b, () => c = 3), () => c = 1);
```

Bang - no braces! You don't even have to indent :-P Don't worry if someone suggests that this is hard to read - after all, why would you have to accomodate other programmers; if worst comes to worst, just recruit your C#ers from old LISPers[1], and noöne will bat an eye at this ;)

*Disclaimer*:

> Don't.

*[1] - No offense meant to LISP or LISPers.*

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ternary, but if the logic is complex it could get ugly/hard to read.

```
c = a ? (b ? 3 : 1) : c;
```

if `a` is false the value of `c` will not change.

You could remove the brackets, but nested ternaries are hard to read and I would suggest they are an antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a && b)
     c = 3;
else if (a && !b)
     c = 1;
```

This will do exactly what you want. But one of the reasons for having brackets is to avoid confusion like this. Adding the bracket will make it much easier to read.